# How to insert result of stored procedure into a table with extra nullable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc returning a set of columns. I want to store the return set into a temp table. I know how to do this: INSERT INTO #TABLE EXEC SP1

Now, the temp table has extra columns that can be NULL. How can I do the same thing and leave the extra columns with NULL values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just explicitly list the column names you want to insert to:

```
INSERT #Table (Column1, Column2, Column3)
EXEC SP1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36b37/1)**

Which is something I would advocate doing anyway in production code. [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) has written an excellent article as to why:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)